# Redux middleware logic

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having a hard time understanding redux middleware and exactly how it gets configured within the Redux store. For example, I have the following examples

```
const store = compose(
  resetRedux('LOGOUT_USER'),
  applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
)(createStore)(rootReducer, initialState);
```

`resetRedux` is a middleware that basically resets the entire redux store when the string `LOGOUT_USER` is dispatched. This works great, however, if I put a `console.log` within the `resetRedux` middleware, it only gets called once, which is strange, considering I'd imagine that action needs to be checked every time in order to be able to decide whether to reset the store.

```
export default function resetMiddleware(types = ['RESET']) {
  return (next) => (reducer, initialState) => {
    const resetTypes = Array.isArray(types) ? types : [types];
    console.log('THIS IS ONLY CALLED ONCE??!')
    const enhanceReducer = (state, action) => {
      if (~resetTypes.indexOf(action.type)) {
        state = undefined;
      }
      return reducer(state, action);
    };
    return next(enhanceReducer, initialState);
  }
};
```

So, I'm curious how this is working when the `console.log` is only called once.

Comment: Side question: where did you see that syntax for use of `compose()` and `createStore()`? It's _valid_, but awful, and I've seen it pop up in several questions lately.  If it's still in the docs somewhere, we need to update the docs to stop teaching that.  The easier to understand syntax would be: `createStore(reducer, preloadedState, composedEnhancers)`

Comment: I've seen it in use, in several starter kits. It's why I was trying to understand the logic. My response to the proposed answer (not sufficient) below:

Yes, I understand function composition, however, if you look at the code above, it doesn't make sense why the console.log statement is only called once. I would imagine that with every action, those conditional checks are made to determine whether to reset the redux store or not... Furthermore, if I place the resetRedux within the applyMiddleware function, it doesn't work. I need to place it outside and use compose as you see above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing and conflating "middleware" and "store enhancers".  The `resetRedux` piece that you've written is actually a "store enhancer", not a middleware.

A real middleware would have its main body executed for every action that is dispatched.  The store enhancer itself is evaluated/executed once, at the time of store creation.  The *reducer* you're returning will be executed for every action, because you're creating a function that wraps around whatever the "real" reducer is that's provided to `createStore`.

As an addendum, the [Redux Tutorials#Implementation Walkthroughs](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/redux-tutorials.md#redux-implementation-walkthroughs) section of my React/Redux links list has several articles that explain how middleware work in Redux.

Comment: This is absolutely the case! I appreciate the feedback and why I was confused. I understood that middlewares are generally applied, using the `applyMiddleware` function, however, the `resetRedux` bit of code did not work there, so it was moved up outside as a `store enhancer` as you mentioned.

So, I'm curious how the resetting does actually work, since it's only called once. Furthermore, if it would be better to move it as a middleware, how it can be configured to work.

Comment: Both middleware and enhancer are defined as factory functions.  The outermost function is the factory, and only ever executed once at store creation time.  Inner methods will be executed multiple times.  The `enhanceReducer` reducer function you defined will be executed every time a dispatched action reaches the store, because that now _is_ the one and only reducer function.  A middleware's inner function will be executed every time an action comes through the middleware pipeline, so it has a chance to handle it.  It's the difference between the "factory" and "the thing the factory returns".

Comment: That's great! I overlooked the fact that the enhancer was, indeed, being called multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Thats what `compose` does,  it takes your passed functions and create a new function that "compose" them.

> **Arguments**
>
> (arguments): The functions to compose. Each function is expected to
>   accept a single parameter. Its return value will be provided as an
>   argument to the function standing to the left, and so on. The
>   exception is the right-most argument which can accept multiple
>   parameters, as it will provide the signature for the resulting
>   composed function. Returns
>
> **Returns (Function):** The final function obtained by composing the given
>   functions from right to left.

You can check the source code [here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/050d42517330f9bbed73d37c13de84ea83a87230/src/compose.js)

Its a typical utility in functional programming, e.g. lodash's also [provide it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.compose), [underscore as well](http://ericstiles.github.io/posts/underscore-compose-functional-javascript/)

Comment: Yes, I understand function composition, however, if you look at the code above, it doesn't make sense why the `console.log` statement is only called once. I would imagine that with every action, those conditional checks are made to determine whether to reset the redux store or not... 

Furthermore, if I place the resetRedux within the `applyMiddleware` function, it doesn't work. I need to place it outside and use `compose` as you see above.